# Views: Using Pager With Single Node, Multiple Fields

Tags: views

I created a node, that has multiple images on it. I want to use this node as the "source" for a views page showing a gallery of images.

I am having a few problems, the first and most major, is that the pager does not work.

I presume that is because all of the images are coming from a single node.

The second problem is more aesthetic; the images are not spaced correctly, and are not distributed across the width. I am not sure how to fix this problem either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Nivo Formatter](http://drupal.org/project/nivo_formatter) to make your image field to a slider. There is no need to build this with views.